# Android notification color in adv is always white

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

this code creates a notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setContentIntent(pIntent)
              .setTicker(title).setWhen(when).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
              .setContentText(contentText).setDefaults(defaults);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
        } else {
            builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
            builder.setColor(color);
        }
        Notification notification = builder.build();
```

But in my AVD  devices all notification are always white.
for example, if `color =  0xff3d8371` it gives the same white color. What's wrong?